# How to make it clear that I'm actually "asking for a friend" and not for myself?

Tags: professionalism, communication, job-search

A programmer (J.) that I know is looking for a new job - and wants it fast because she is in a bad environment right now. I was going to post for her in a public developers slack group, as I'm sure that it will lead to pretty good results, but I realized that the main HR/recruiter from my company is part of the #jobs slack channel.

J. has a lot of the same skills that I do (Python, SQL, etc), is in the same location as me, and only has 2 years of experience - just like me.

**How can I phrase the post in a way that makes it clear that I'm *actually* posting for a friend, and not for myself?** I am not looking for a new job and *definitely* don't want my company to accidentally suspect that I am.

Comment: Why not suggest to her to join the slack and ask for herself?

Comment: @HorusKol generally ppl who are looking for new jobs don't want to post for themselves, as it can make things super uncomfortable at their current roles if their boss/coworkers see it :)

Comment: @giraffe36 And therefore they ask friends to post the message and make the friend feel super uncomfortable in their current role if their boss/coworkers see it? It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Given you mention it's a Slack channel, define "public". Is this within your company? Or is this completely open anyone who wishes to join regardless of affiliation?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Here are some options for you**

1. **Create a fake account for the group.** It is public right, so anyone can basically join with ease? Just make a new account to do this with.
2. **Send an email to the HR person asking if they can add your friend to their list of people to hire.** Let the HR recruiter at your company in on the scheme. Maybe they know somewhere your friend can go. Why necessarily hide it from them? Just send them your friend's resume.
3. **Fiddle with the details to make it not you.** Change the gender, age, university of graduation, etc. Make J a "he" to test the waters. Or say that they are coming in from [city across country] to [live with spouse/take care of parent] Most people are insufficiently cynical enough to think that someone would deliberately lie to throw someone off. The recruiter would see the skills as similar but the stories as different and move on.
4. **Ask a friend with a different skillset to do the submission.** Run it through another person in the group.

Comment: As a variant on #2, send your in-house a recruiter a message with "hey, a friend of mine is looking for a job, can I send her CV to you so you can see if it matches any of our current openings?" By going to the recruiter first, you remove suspicion that you're trying to go behind his back.

Answer (score 17):

At the end of your post, add something like "I have been keeping an eye out for a suitable position with my employer for them, but they don't match our current openings so I'd like to help them find a good position elsewhere."

That both expresses your loyalty to your employer and to your friend.

Comment: The ficticious friend is used so often... but I like this, plus 1.